# How to remove previous DOM element after using .cloneNode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a basic script to duplicate a div called `imgcont` 150 times.

Right now, it's duplicating correctly but I want to remove the previous div. Example sequence:

- #imgcont1 loads
- #imgcont2 loads, deletes #imgcont1
- #imgcont3 loads, deletes #imgcont2
- #imgcont4 loads, deletes #imgcont3

Make sense? Codepen example here: http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/clHCK

```
var i = 0;
var xpos = 1;
var original = document.getElementById('imgcont');

function duplicate() {
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
var randomcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
clone.id = "imgcont" + ++i;
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
$(clone).css("background-color", randomcolor);
$(clone).css("left", xpos);
}
var p = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
duplicate();
p += 1;
xpos += 3;
if (p == 150) clearInterval(interval);
}, 10);
```

Comment: Why do all that work? Seems like you should just update the ID and css properties of the existing element.

Comment: ...but to answer your question, instead of `.appendChild`, do this: `original.replaceChild(clone, original.firstElementChild)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `container_node.replaceChild(new_node,old_node)` that is supported in all major browsers.

```
container = original.parentNode;
container.replaceChild(clone,original);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading next and deleting previous, means always one div visible, right?
Why not change the attributes of the one div without cloning?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic:

```
var remID = +currentNode.id.slice(7) - 1;
$('#imgcont' + remID).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to delete the previous element, you can use the jQuery **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method:

```
function duplicate() {
    // ...
    // .eq(-2) is the the element to be cloned
    // .eq(-1) is the the cloned element
    $("[id^='imgcont']").eq(-2).remove();
}
```

But I would use the jQuery **[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** method.
Refactorized using **jQuery**

```
  (function ($, undefined) {
    var colors = [ /* many colors */ ];

    var i = 0,
        p = 0,
        xpos = 1,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
          duplicate();
          //xpos += 3;
          if (++p == 150) clearInterval(interval);
        }, 10);

    function duplicate() {
      var randomcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
          original = $("[id^='imgcont']"),
          clone = original.clone()
            .attr("id", "imgcont" + (++i))
            .css({"background-color": randomcolor /*, "left": xpos*/ });

      original.replaceWith(clone);
    }

  })(jQuery);
```

---

But why to clone an element to remove it later?
I would modify just the attributes to that element instead.

```
  (function($, undefined) {
    var colors = [ /* many colors */ ];
    var n = 0,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
          var randcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
              item = $("#imgcont");
          item.css({"background-color": randcolor });
          if (++n == 150) clearInterval(interval);
        }, 10);
  })(jQuery);
```